# Ionic - Changing width of ion-searchbar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am wondering how I can change the width of an ion-searchbar and its container class "toolbar-content" in Ionic 3

I can simply create a class with these css attributes to alter the width of just the searchbar:

```
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
```

However, this leaves its auto-generated container div to still have the full original width.

Here is what the searchbar looks like with the css mentioned above

[image]

However the container div still has the full width. (see image below)

[image]

As seen in the images, despite the actual ion-searchbar width changing, there is still a div with the toolbar-content class that does not change width.

I have tried overriding the width of the toolbar-content and toolbar-content-ios classes, however, this does not seem to work.

Here is the HTML for the header that is used:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar mode="ios">
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button ion-button icon-only>
                <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-searchbar id="home-search" placeholder="Search Groups & Connections" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)" (ionClear)="resetFilter($event)"></ion-searchbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only>
                <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Thank you very much for your time and any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try removing padding `.toolbar .searchbar{padding: 0px}` in your css

Comment: @MohanGopi there actually isn't any padding, I should have mentioned that I already tried that my mistake. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding this CSS to the ion-buttons:

```
margin: auto;
flex-basis: 50px;
```

Turns out the search bar will then fill the remaining space and the buttons on either side will be centered like I wanted.